# Select two distinct sets of rows for one column in one statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, union-all

I have a table with 2 columns:
`name`, `percentage`

I have a 100 rows in this table, and want to make a query that selects the 5 rows with the *smallest* percentage value and the 5 rows with the *largest* percentage value.

Normally I would do this with `limit` and `offset` but it will select only one of the outcome groups I seek. I wonder if there is a way of selecting both.

I have been looking for a solution for a while, and I thought about FETCH, but I don't really succeed in using right.

Comment: Use a UNION. That's would still be in 'one statement'.

Comment: So do you have your answer here?

Answer (score 1):

#### [`UNION ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION)

```
(
SELECT name, percentage
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY percentage
LIMIT  5
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT name, percentage
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY percentage DESC
LIMIT  5
);
```

You need **parenthesis**, to apply `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` to nested `SELECT` statements of a `UNION` query. I quote [the manual here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION):

> `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` can be attached to a subexpression if it is
>   enclosed in parentheses. Without parentheses, these clauses will be
>   taken to apply to the result of the `UNION`, not to its right-hand input expression.

`UNION` (without `ALL`) would remove duplicates in the result. A useless effort if you don't expect dupes.

#### Subquery with [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html)

```
SELECT name, percentage
FROM  (
   SELECT *
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY percentage) AS rn_min
        , row_number() OVER (ORDER BY percentage DESC) AS rn_max
   FROM   tbl
   ) x
WHERE rn_min < 6
OR    rn_max < 6;
```

This collapses duplicates like `UNION` would. Performance will be similar, probably a bit slower than the first one.

Either way, order by additional columns to break ties in a controlled manner. As is, you get arbitrary rows from groups of peers sharing the same `percentage`.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know union all, i had been trying with + !